# Problems running python3 and selenium on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, github

I have some problems trying to run this python script in terminal.
I downloaded this from a [Github link](https://github.com/mrgretwon/fut_sniping_bot), where everything is vague explained for each platform which is why I am asking it here.
Whenever I do cd /user/name/desktop/filename/ and type: 'make run'.
I get this back, which the first line is correct but the other lines are not correct. Which causes that the script is not loading up correctly.
All asked programs and other stuff are downloaded correctly according to terminal.

So if anyone could please explain if I'm missing something in the python3 installation or if the codes provided on the Github are wrong.

Would appreciate it!

```html
make run
find -name '*.pyc' -delete
find: illegal option -- n
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you try to change Makefile to put `find . -name ...` ?

Comment: First 3 lines are now correct I'm getting this new error now: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.bot import Bot
ImportError: No module named src.bot
make: *** [run] Error 1`

Comment: try `PYTHONPATH=. make run`

Comment: Still get the same error back

Comment: what is the actual error here? When you execute `make run`?

Comment: I think the make file may be either incorrect (as noted above) or platform/shell specific.